# How to solve limit of this function?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, fractions, limits-without-lhopital

> $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^2 -3x+2}{(x^3-2x^2+x)^2}
> $

I have tried:
1) substitution of $x$ by $1+\epsilon$(this gets long)
2) factorizing and simplifying

I have to be rigorous and not supposed to use L'Hopital

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^+}\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{x^2(x-1)^4}=\lim_{x\rightarrow1^+}\frac{x-2}{x^2(x-1)^3}=-\infty$$ and it's
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-}\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{x^2(x-1)^4}=\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-}\frac{x-2}{x^2(x-1)^3}=+\infty$$

Comment: is this a proof?

Comment: Yes! Because $x-1\rightarrow0$ and $1-2\neq0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\frac{x^2-3x+2} {(x^3-2x^2+x)^2} = \frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{(x (x-1)^2)^2} = \frac {x-2} {x^4(x-1)}$$

Thus the limit is determined by the behaviour of $\frac 1 {x-1}$ near $1$, which in turn is determined by the behaviour of $\frac 1 x$ near $0$.

Answer (score 0):

In
$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^2 -3x+2}{(x^3-2x^2+x)^2}
$,
let
$x = y+1$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{x^2 -3x+2}{(x^3-2x^2+x)^2}
&=\frac{y(y-1)}{(y+1)^2(x^2-2x+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{y(y-1)}{(y+1)^2((x-1)^2)^2}\\
&=\frac{y(y-1)}{(y+1)^2y^4}\\
&=\frac{y-1}{(y+1)^2y^3}\\
\end{array}
$

so the limit is
$\pm\infty$
depending how
$y \to 0$.